Stripe retrieve customer with related subscriptions (no plan name attached)
--in TEST MODE--
I am retrieving the customer with cus_xxxx
In order to avoid multiple API calls, i expand the customer object by requesting 'subscriptions' related to that customer ID
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query([
        "expand[]" => 'subscriptions'
    ])

But the subscriptions object does not return the plan name, as it would when retrieving the product itself.
https://docs.stripe.com/api/products/retrieve
 [id] => prod_Mxxxxxxx
..
 [name] => My plan Name

Should it be that way, or am i missing something?

I'd recommend listing Subscriptions with the Customer ID in the customer argument, which will yield the same list as the Customer's subscriptions, but this time you can expand[]=>'data.plan.product'and this way get the Product name.

Hi Lucky2501, that gives me an error [message] => This property cannot be expanded (items) .. even that string is marked as 'expandable'

Ah yes - my bad. Because it's a list, you need to start with data in your expand, and because you're limited to 4 levels, you can't do data.items.data.price.product. It's okay, you can expand data.plan.product instead. That works (I'll edit my answer)

That returns same error..i've tried to reduce till 1 level, all with error. But what did the trick is subscriptions.data.plan.product .. not sure if it is a preferred way, but it works :)

I get it, you were still making the Customer retrieve call - different from the one I was suggesting. But if it works for you - that's all good :)

Yes, that's true..my fault. Just realized that. I works when listing Subscriptions with the Customer ID in the customer argument. Thank youuu for pointing out to the right direction. You rock!

I didn't actually know you could expand the Customer subscriptions so good to know!
